# Is it allowed by Apple to customize localizedFallbackTitle for local authentication?

Tags: ios, app-store, touch-id

Can I change localizedFallbackTitle for LAContext? I am asking because this property exists in public header files but it is not listed in the [docs for LAContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/LAContext).
Will Apple reject my app if I change this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Apple will not reject it, Since it is in the public header you are able to use it.

Apple did add this property to the Api diff documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/LocalAuthentication.html